# Modify node.js/express.js to be able to accept unicode headers?

Tags: node.js, unicode, express

For some reason, when passing unicode characters in the header key, the request does not reach express.js framework, it kind of disappears:

```
 # this never gets to my application code
 curl localhost:9981/v1/test/bucket -X PUT -H "x-container-meta-♫: something" -i

 # this gets to my application code
 curl localhost:9981/v1/test/bucket -X PUT -H "x-container-meta-not_unicode: something" -i

 # this also gets to my application code
 curl localhost:9981/v1/test/bucket -X PUT -H "x-container-meta-unicode_in_value: ♫" -i
```

Which part of node.js / express.js should I modify to be able to process unicode headers?

Answer (score 0):

For headers, Unicode characters are not allowed. The proper way to include Unicode or other non-ASCII characters is to use [encoded-words](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) instead.

Browser/web server implementations vary in behavior when it comes to non-ASCII characters (including ASCII control characters) in headers.

Comment: But, Openstack Swift appears to fully support unicode in headers.

Comment: @mscdex could you maybe have a look at my question [link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440178/frontend-apparently-requires-unicode-string)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP essentially only supports ASCII (it's slightly more complicated than that, but close enough). [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) establishes how to encode other string encodings like UTF-8. Many web servers probably implement the RFC. Django appears to implement it.

I have successfully used the [rfc2047](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfc2047) NPM package in express.js to decode UTF-8 headers that come from a Django API backend. It probably wouldn't be difficult to make an express.js middleware that automatically decodes all headers.