# Frontend apparently requires Unicode String

Tags: node.js, express, unicode, odata

I am building the backend for a web application in node.js for which the customer wants to keep the frontend unchanged.
The old backend used SAP and a so called OData Service for communication, that I have no clue about.
I am using Express to handle the requests of the frontend.
Looking at the response of the old backend (Chrome debugger), I can see, that it passed date strings, in the following format:

```
"\/Date(1636329600000)\/"
```

I failed to get my response which is send to the frontend to look the same.

I am using (simplified)

```
let responseHeader = {
        'content-type' : 'multipart/mixed; charset=utf-8',  
      }
res.set(responseHeader)
res.send(response)
```

where I tried different formats for the response date string in order to get "/Date(1636329600000)/" in the frontend:

```
response= "\/Date(1636329600000)\/" -> in frontend became  "/Date(1636329600000)/"
response= "\\/Date(1636329600000)\\/" -> in frontend became  "\\/Date(1636329600000)\\/"
```

How can I let node know, that is should parse "\/Date(1636329600000)\/" as a unicode string? I really appreciate your help.

Best Jogala

Comment: i don't see what unicode has anything to do with this.

Comment: @Joe thanks for your comment. How would you name that problem?

Comment: It's unclear from your question if your problem is parsing the request, or formatting a response.  You mention both requests and responses in your post.  Can you provide a more succinct example of what doesn't work (code) and what you expect/need it to do?

Comment: I don't know if I have to modify the response or parse the request in a different manner...  Like you see in my question, I tried to format the response in different ways ( response = "\/Date(1636329600000)\/", response = "\\/Date(1636329600000)\\/" ) without success. I don't know how to modify the parsing in order to get the desired "\/Date(1636329600000)\/" showing in the response arriving in the forntend.

Comment: Are you sure that `response= "\\/Date(1636329600000)\\/"` is actually showing up wrong?  Or is that just how it shows up in the debugger?  Because that's what I'd expect to work from an escaping standpoint.